# Lefschetz Theorems (Complex Geo by D Huybrechts)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

I have a couple of questions on a proof from Daniel Huybrechts' Complex Geometry [Complex Geometry](https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf) on pages $134:$

> **Corollary 3.3.6** If $X$ is a compact Kahler manifold, then $Pic^°(X)$ is in a
>   natural way a complex torus of dimension $b_1(X)$.
>
> *Proof*. We use the bidegree decomposition (Corollary $3.2.12$): $H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) =
> H^{1,0}(X) \oplus H^{0,1}(X)$, the fact that $\overline{H^{1,0}(X)} = H^{0,1}(X)$, and $H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) =
> H^1(X, \mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} =(H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$. This shows that $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to
> H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) \to H^{0,1}(X)$ is injective with discrete image that generates $H^{0,1}(X)$
>   as a real vector space. (???) In other words, $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})
> \subset H^{0,1}(X)$ is a lattice. Thus,
>   it suffices to show that this inclusion $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})
> \subset H^{0,1}(X)$ coincides with the
>   one given by the exponential sequence. (???) But this is immediate from Lemma
>   $3.3.1.$

Q1: I don't understand the argument why the composition $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to
H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) \to H^{0,1}(X)$ is injective with discrete image.

The first map $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to
H^1(X, \mathbb{C})$ is induced by canonical inclusion $ \mathbb{Z} \to  \mathbb{C}$ of locally constant sheaves. Why ist this map injective? Obviously the image is real and since $\overline{H^{1,0}(X)} = H^{0,1}(X)$ it is fully contained in $H^{1,0}(X)$, that's fine. It's also ok that the image is discrete as $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated as $ \mathbb{Z}$- module . now, why it generates $H^{0,1}(X)$ as $ \mathbb{R}$-space?

Recall, that on previous page $133$ between Lemma $3.3.1$ and Prop $3.3.2$ occurs a similar statement that $H^1(X, \mathbb{R}) \to
H^1(X, \mathbb{C})$ is injective. I think that the argument that this map is injective is quite similar to that one that $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to
H^1(X, \mathbb{C})$ from above is injective. One possible argument that came me in mind was to use flatness of $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$. Huybrechts nowhere in his book used this terminology thus I think he uses another argument for injectivity of $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to
H^1(X, \mathbb{C})$. Which one?

Q2: Why does suffices to show that the inclusion $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})
\subset H^{0,1}(X)$ from Q_1 coincides with that
one given by the exponential sequence (page 132) to show the claim?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, $H^1(X,\mathbb Z) \to H^1(X,\mathbb C)$ is induced by inclusion of constant sheaves     $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$. If one looks at the short exact sequence of sheaves $$0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C\to\mathbb C/\mathbb Z\to 0$$

Where $\mathbb C/\mathbb Z$ is the quotient sheaf, coinciding with the constant sheaf of quotient group. Then using long exact sequence of cohomology, the injectivity of $H^1(X,\mathbb Z) \to H^1(X,\mathbb C) $ is equivalent to $H^0(X,\mathbb C/\mathbb Z) = \mathbb C/\mathbb Z\to H^1(X,\mathbb Z) $ being the zero map. Which follows from surjectivity of $H^0(X,\mathbb C)=\mathbb C\to \mathbb C/\mathbb Z$.

Now $H^1(X,\mathbb Z) $ generates $H^{0,1}(X)$ as real vector space because $H^1(X,\mathbb R) \cong H^1(X,\mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$ (and similarly for $\mathbb C$). Let $\alpha\in H^{0,1}(X)$, and $\bar\alpha\in H^{1,0}(X)$, then $\alpha+\bar\alpha\in H^1(X,\mathbb R)$ and is generated by integral cohomology, say $\alpha+\bar\alpha=\sum a_i\omega_i$. Then one can just project $\alpha+\bar\alpha$ back to $H^{0,1}(X)$ and recover an expression for $\alpha$ (since $\bar\alpha$ vanishes under the projection $H^1(X,\mathbb C) \to H^{0,1}(X)$.)

For Q2, recall that we wish to consider $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$, which is defined using exponential sheaf sequence as the kernel of first Chern class map $c_1: H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^*) \to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$. It is the same as the image of $H^{0,1}(X)\cong H^1(X,\mathcal O_X) \to H^1(X,\mathcal O_X^*) $, so by first isomorphism theorem it is isomorphic to $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X) $ quotient by the image of $H^1(X,\mathbb Z) \to H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)$. But this map is the inclusion of lattice as discussed above, so $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$ is isomorphic to a complex vector space quotient by lattice, which is a complex torus.

By the way, the complex dimension of the complex torus should be $b_1(X)/2$ instead of $b_1(X)$.

Comment: one remark on your answer: you and the author use in the argument the identity $
H^1(X, \mathbb{R})  =H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$. Are you implicitly using the universal coefficient thoerem at that point or can that here be be observed from the given context in an easier way? The point is that in the proof above Huybrechts used $H^1(X, \mathbb{C}) =
H^1(X, \mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} =(H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ without loosing

Comment: a few words on universal coefficient thoerem in the the book and thus I wasn't pretty sure if he just assumes that the reader is familar with it or if this identity is an "obvious" consequence from previous results contained in the book.

Comment: Yes I think the universal coefficient theorem is needed. I don't think Huybrechts mentioned this in his book except perhaps the appendix, since he assumed the readers know a bit about singular cohomology. In fact to be completely rigorous we need to prove that the integral singular cohomology is isomorphic to the sheaf cohomology too. But I think you can assume this fact, or simply read the details in a topology book.